# Blank Xamarin watchOS app does not deploy to device - "Execution failed"

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.ios, .net-6.0, watchos

When creating an empty Xamarin iOS project via Visual Studio for Mac 2022 "iOS -> App -> Xamarin -> Single View App" and then adding a watchOS project "watchOS -> App -> Xamarin -> WatchKit App" the build is working fine.

Nuget package restore issue could be solved by adding `<ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>` to the Watch App Project Reference in the iOS app project file.

The build for all three projects (iOS App, WatchOS Extension, WatchOS App) succeeds without any errors. When trying to deploy the watchOS target to any device, either Simulator or physical Apple Watch, VS just shows "Execution failed" and doesn't give any more detail why it failed.

While researching for a solution we stumpled across a [GitHub issue in the xamarin-macios repo](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/8955) that states that watchOS will not be supported with .NET 6. We haven't found an official statement regarding watchOS not being supported anymore. Does that mean it is not possible to deploy a Xamarin watchOS app and also watchOS not supported within MAUI?

Current setup:

- Operating System: Mac OS X 12.6.2
- Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 for Mac, Version 17.4.3 (build 21)
- Runtime: .NET 6.0.12 (64-bit), Architecture: X64
- NuGet Version: 6.3.1.1
- Xcode 14.2 (21534), Build 14C18
- Xamarin.iOS, Version: 16.1.1.27 (Visual Studio Enterprise)

Deploying a blank watchOS app in Visual Studio results in "Execution failed"